# "Add member" Firebase does not work

Tags: database, firebase, addition, member, collaboration

I have a project on Firebase and I want to give other people access to my database. I go to Permissions, press Add member, and enter their email, but all I get is this error:

> Server Error There's a problem at our end.
>
> Please try again. If the problem persists, please let us know using
>   the "Send feedback" link below. Thanks!
>
> Tracking Number: 5501926321690232750

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm seeing the same error. Any help on this would be great.

Comment: I wanted to add my friend as an project editor and was getting this error. It worked when I added him as an owner. This is ok for now as I trust him but it's not ideal and I will convert him back to editor as soon as I stop getting this error